# やつしてみたかった　expression meaning

Tags: translation

キスってやつしてみたかったな

I've never read this expression before. I just know that やつす means *to be absorbed, to lose yourself to*, so I was gessing that maybe in this case it could mean:

"I wanted to lose myself in a kiss"

I am I right? Or does it have a different meaning?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're parsing it wrongly. It's not the verb やつす, but the noun やつ and the verb する.

キス - kiss
って - colloquial form of という
やつ - in this case やつ simply means "thing"

So we have "thing called a kiss" so far.

して - te-form of する
みたかった - from みる which attached to the te-form of another verb means to try doing something
な - emotive final particle

Put it together and you get "wanted to try doing".

So a very literal translation would be:

> I wanted to try doing that thing called a kiss

You might have been confused because there is no を particle between やつ and する but these particles are often omitted in casual speech.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I understand now! I got it completely wrong, your explanation was very useful!